# Downloaded Ubuntu 14 LTS, but on extraction shows all files broken

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I am new to LINUX. So, I wanted to test it on USB. Used Universal-USB-Installer.exe downloaded from http://www.pendrivelinux.com to create a bootable USB. Then downloaded Ubuntu-14.04.2 Desktop 64 Bit iso from Ubuntu site. The extraction got 149 errors. Almost all files broken. Still went ahead and tried the Bootable USB drive on Acer Aspire 4741G. It boots up but I get a message as follows:

```
SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvin et al
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot:_
```

Anybody knows where did I go wrong or the problem is with the ISO itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you start over, to ensure you have a proper Ubuntu image. I also suggest that you verify that the file you downloaded is correct, before making the USB stick and trying to boot it.

So here are some steps for you:

1. Download an image from [Ubuntu releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) I suggest the the stable version of the desktop ones. (14.04.2 at the time of this writing)
2. Calculate the SHA256 checksum of the image you have downloaded in step 1. On Windows you can use [this link](http://www.labtestproject.com/using_windows/step_by_step_using_sha256sum_on_windows_xp.html)
3. Copy the result of the checksum (to clipboard)
4. From the URL in step 1, click on the file "SHA256SUMS" (Sorry I can't give the link directly, I'm restricted)
5. Press Control-F on your keyboard, and paste the checksum you copied in step 3. It should highlight one of the checksums in the page. The name next to the highlighted checksum should match the file you downloaded.

If it doesn't, let us know, the problem is with your download method.

If it does, continue with re-making the USB stick and booting it, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Good answer! Upvoted (just removed the "good luck" and improved readability)  Is there something else you would like to link to?  Leave it in a comment @Fabby below and I'll edit it in for you!  ;-)